# How to make gridlayout in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to make grid layout in kivymd. GridLayout created but width not filling the screen. How can extend the width of column to fit the screen in kivymd?

I have used example from kivymd docs and used it create a grid layout.

**app.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from main_screen_str import helper_string
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 500)


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main_screen"))

        self.main_str = Builder.load_string(helper_string)

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        screen.add_widget(self.main_str)
        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This is builder string. The gridlayout created but the width not fitting the screen.
How can I extend the width for individual column in the gridlayout?

**build string**

```
helper_string = """
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main_screen'
        
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 3
        
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "android"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "android"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "android"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "android"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "android"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "android"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MDIconBuuton Documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#id1):

> By default, MDIconButton button has a size (dp(48), dp (48))

And the `GridLayout` will use those size values to size the columns. You can adjust the column size by adjusting the size of the `MDIconButtons`. So, if you just add:

```
size_hint_x: 0.33
```

to each `MDIconButton`, each column will be one third the width of the `MainScreen`.